# @Html.RenderAction with Ajax Form ASP.NET Mvc3 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a scenario where i need some code setup when a control renders. I have a widget that'll be used on a number of pages called a QuickRate:

I'm trying to call it like so in my cshtml file:

```
<div class="dragbox" id="quick-rate">
<h2>Retrieve a Quick Rate</h2>
@Html.Action("Create", "QuickRate")
</div>
```

and then in the create on the QuickRateController.cs I have:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
var model = new QuickRateModel();
    model.Products = currentUser.GetProducts(dataRepository).ToSelectList(p => p.ProductId, p => p.ProductName);
return View("QuickRateResult", model);
}
```

i then have a QuickRatePartial.cshtml file that contains the following:

```
@model Project.Web.Models.QuickRateModel

@{
    Layout = "";
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "quick-rate-content"
    };
}
<div class="clearfix">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetQuickRate", "QuickRate", null, options, new { @id="quick-rate-form" }))
 {
        <fieldset>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, Model.Products)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId)
         <select data-val="true" name="DropDown1" data-bind="
                                options: Items1,
                                optionsText :'ItemName',
                                value: SelectedName
                                ">
                            </select>

        <select data-val="true" name="DropDown2" id="DropDown2" data-val-required="Please select an Item." data-bind="
        options: SelectedItem().MoreItems,
        optionsText: 'Text',
        optionsValue: 'Text',
        value: MoreItem,
        optionsCaption: 'Select One'
        "></select>
        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MoreItems)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Get Quick Rate" />
        </div>
        <div id="quick-rate-content"></div>
        </fieldset>
 }
</div>
```

try as i might I can't get the form to render at all.. just wondering if you had any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You've named the file quickratepartial.cshtml but in the action you are looking for a view called quickrateresult. Is this correct?